# Bad file descriptor socket.accept

Tags: python

The code I'm working on compiles fine but after the web server sends the message to the client, the server quits with the following error. Also, my code never seems to reach the IOError block when using serverAddr:serverPort/test.html. Which should return '404 page not found' By looking at the traceback I think it might just be a problem with my machine's setup but I'm not entirely sure. Could it be a problem with my code?

```
#Tasks: Create a socket, bind to a specific address and port, send and receive an HTTP        packet.
#Description: Web server should handle one HTTP request at a time. So the serve closes its TCP connection after response.
#Accept and parse the HTTP request, get the requested file from the server (i.e.   HelloWorld.html), create a response
#message with the requested file and header lines, then send the response to the client.
#Error handling: If file not found then send HTTP "404 Not Found" Message back to client.

#import socket module: here we are using a low-level networking class from Python
from socket import * 

#create the socket that belongs to the server.
#AF_INTET represents the address families and protocols.
#SOCK_STREAM represents the socket type
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 

#Prepare a server socket 

#Define variable for serverPort; we'll use the one in the helper page of the book
serverPort = 51350
#Define host address
serverHost = ''

#Bind the socket to the local host machine address and port
serverSocket.bind((serverHost, serverPort))

#Listen for TCP connections from the client
serverSocket.listen(1)

#Verify setup for receiving
print 'Server is ready to receive'

while True: 
 #Establish the connection 
 print 'Ready to serve...' 
 #When the server receive a request from the client it must establish a new connectionSocket and begin taking in the data.
 connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
 try: 
 #Take data from connectionSocket and place in message.
 #.recvfrom doesn't work because it expects data and return address variables.
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024) 

    #uncomment for header information
    #print message

     #parse the message
    filename = message.split()[1] 
    f = open(filename[1:]) 
    outputdata = f.read();

 #Send one HTTP header line into socket 
    connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')

 #Send the content of the requested file to the client 
    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)): 
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i]) 

    connectionSocket.close() 

 except IOError:

 #Send response message for file not found 
    connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found')
    connectionSocket.close()

 #Close client socket 
 serverSocket.close() 


Traceback:
Server is ready to receive
Ready to serve...
Ready to serve...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw2.py", line 35, in <module>
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",      line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Ready to serve...' is printed twice, so it is dying on the second connection after the first one worked.  This happens because you close the server socket in the loop.  Also, you never do f.close to close the file that you open.

Comment: I've moved the last statement indentation to align with the while True: statement but I don't get a '404 Not Found' message when I enter a file that the server does not have. What causes this?